# Very low quality flag coming from "Help and Improvement" queue got declined

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, help-improvement

In the "Help and Improvement" queue I was presented [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58189420). At the time I saw it, the entire question was:

> ### in an Office JavaScript addin, is it possible to prompt the user to open a local JSON file and then process its contents?
>
> Nothing to add to the subject, which I hope is clear. Most of the
>   results I get searching for this are old and inconclusive. A
>   definitive and up to date response would be appreciated.

In my opinion there is nothing I could have edited to make this a good question so I chose to mark it as "very low quality" (had I found it elsewhere I probably would have flagged it as "too broad").

To my surprise my flag was declined giving the following reason:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

Was my action wrong and if so, what would have been appropriate?

Comment: Skip would've been appropriate, or leaving the H&I queue altogether...

Comment: In  general, never click the "very low quality" link in the Help and Improvement review queue. It is only there so you can work on your declined flag rate ...

Comment: @NickA _... or leaving the H&I queue altogether_ Yeah, I start considering this :-(

Comment: @rene Looks you're right. From the 3 times I clicked it, 1 was helpful, 1 disputed and 1 declined.

Comment: Most unaware users assume that link means *this post should not have been here* and I think that was it initial design goal. That path was never finished/implemented so that is why we now have to deal with this queue that is far from effective and hardly any means to make it effective.

Comment: The question doesn't look *particularly* terrible (compared to many), it's on-topic and looks reasonably scoped, but *Most of the search results I get for this are old and inconclusive* makes me think it may be a dupe, if there are older questions that ask the same thing. If it's not a dupe, then it shouldn't be closed (or deleted), which means that VLQ wouldn't be appropriate. (VLQ flags on questions are pretty hard to justify in most cases anyway)

Comment: As Shog says, in the duplicate: *Regardless of whether or not it ends up in /review or the mod queue (and most of the time, it'll end up in both at least for a little while...) VLQ flags on questions that should be closed just create unnecessary overhead - someone else has to spend more time thinking about why the question needs to be closed because you didn't specify.*

Comment: And a very long-standing open request to have the VLQ flag removed for questions: [It shouldn’t be possible to flag questions as Very Low Quality](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/195673)

Comment: Your VLQ on [how to fix error during installation of PyUpdater](//stackoverflow.com/q/58186092) was marked helpful automatically when enough people flagged it as 'unsalvagable' in the review queue, and [Support in app update not getting new Update available callback even after 10 hour , but when open play store we see update is available](//stackoverflow.com/q/58091647) was marked disputed because the review outcome was 'requires editing'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you the extensive information, especially the in-depth investigation of my flags. I've definitely learned my lesson to never ever click that link again ;-)